# C++ menu avoid repetition

Tags: c++, file, menu

Thanks for looking at my question in advanced. It may be quite a simple one!

I have a menu where the user can select which file they wish to run through the system.

The code below is what my menu options do:

```
int menuLoop = 1;
int userChoice;
std::string getInput;

while(menuLoop == 1)
{
    std::cout << "Menu\n\n" 
         << "1. 20 names\n"
         << "2. 100 names\n"
         << "3. 500 names\n"
         << "4. 1000 names\n"
         << "5. 10,000 names\n"
         << "6. 50,000 names\n\n";
    std::cin >> userChoice;

    std::string getContent;

    if(userChoice == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "\n20 names\n"; 
        std::ifstream openFile("20.txt");
    }
    else if(userChoice == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "\n100 names\n"; 
        std::ifstream openFile("1C.txt");
    }
    else if(userChoice == 3)
    {
        std::cout << "\n500 names\n"; 
        std::ifstream openFile("5C.txt");
    }
    else if(userChoice == 4)
    {
        std::cout << "\n1000 names\n"; 
        std::ifstream openFile("1K.txt");
    }
    else if(userChoice == 5)
    {
        std::cout << "\n10,000 names\n"; 
        std::ifstream openFile("10K.txt");
    }
    else if(userChoice == 6)
    {
        std::cout << "\n50,000 names\n"; 
        std::ifstream openFile("50K.txt");
    }
```

The code that follows in the while loop deals with the values that are in the selected file, but the code is the same for each option. The next line is:

```
if(openFile.is_open())
```

Because of the way I have done it, it is saying "openFile" is undefined, which I completely understand but I was wondering whether anyone knows how I could get around?

Comment: try switching instead of the if-else ladder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `openFile` just once earlier in the `while` loop like so:

```
std::ifstream openFile;
```

This gives you an `std::ifstream` that is not associated with any particular file. Then in each of your `if` statements use [`std::ifstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) rather than the `std::ifstream` constructor:

```
openFile.open("20.txt");
```

Of course, make sure each one has the correct file name.

This way, the `openFile` object's scope will be the `while` loop but you can open a different file depending on your condition.

Comment: The bigger problem is that their code isn't data driven. @user814628's answer is better as it removes the need for tiptoeing around scoping issues.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like so:

```
const MAX_OPTION = 6;
std::array< std::string, MAX_OPTION > filenames = {"20.txt","1C.txt","5C.txt","1K.txt","10K.txt","50k.txt"};

//your while loop
//...
cin >> userChoice;
//assert userChoice >= 0 < filenames.size
const std::string& filename = filenames[ userChoice ];
std::ifstream openFile(filename.c_str());
```